# Text not showing as label in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add label to the nodes in a D3 force layout, but there seems to be some issue with it. All the text just shows up on top of the screen, overlapping on each other. Here is the code snippet:

```
var link = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line");

var node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .on('click', clicked);

var text = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements piling up on the top left corner of the SVG (which is the origin) is a symptom of several problems, among them:

- `NaN` for the positions
- Not setting the positions
- Not translating the element
- Not including the element in the `tick`function

As you have a force directed chart, the last one is the obvious reason.

Solution: You have to include the `text` in your `ticked` function.

```
function ticked() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    text.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```